# Installation without any SQL tools

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When installing [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) Professional I choose only the following items:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Installation Choices]

However, after the installation is complete, I see my computer full of software I didn't want, for example:

- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Framework
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Data-Tier Application Project
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects (x64)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 x64 ENU
- Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing Wizard 1.4
- Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
- Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types (x64)

Is there a way to install Visual Studio without all of these "extras"?

Comment: I'm not sure - based on your question it would appear not. However, what's the problem? They're not going to fill up any modern HDD or slow things down. I expect they're somehow referenced by the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll stuff, so they've come in as a dependency. Really though, I wouldn't worry about it. In fact, it's also possible they've come in because VS has some data management tools similar to SQL Server Management Studio, so these components could be dependencies of that stuff.

Comment: Yes, that is most certainly the case. However just because they don't occupy a considerable amount of space or slow things down, doesn't mean they should be there, nor even be installed. As I expected there's probably no way to install VS without all that unwanted software.

Comment: My question is - why don't you want it?

Comment: There should be an option to choose whether the user wants to install this software or not.
Since my installed programs list becomes huge (which annoys me, I know, I'm weird), I normally uninstall them all. But if later I want to install, lets say C++, the VS installer simply re installs them all over again.

Comment: My point is, there's no point having an option to skip installing them if they're required.